# Excel VBA Populate Counter Variable via input box

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have some code I put together with the macro recorder and some trial and error that I run and it works fine but Id like to add an input box that will populate the counter value as an input by me instead of hard coded.

Put simply I am trawling through data in a single column using the find function. Most of the time 10 cycles will do the trick to find that data and clear the content. I would like the option to change the counter via an input box instead of editing my code.

Sure its easy but I'm stumped

```
Sub Searchclear()
    'Search and clear Macro

    Do Until counter = 10
        counter = counter + 1
        On Error Resume Next

        Range("B2:B4000").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="Date Range ", After:=ActiveCell,
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    Loop

End Sub
```

The following code is the same as above but with my attempt with input box

```
Sub Searchcleara()
    ' Search and clear Macro

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = InputBox("Enter number of Cycles")
    Do Until counter = InputBox
        counter = counter + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("B2:B4000").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="Date Range", After:=ActiveCell,
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please fix the `formatting` of your `code`? I read somewhere to NOT use TAB for indentation as it doesn't work well with SO, use spaces, but you can always preview your post before posting. You'll find much better responses with a well formatted post. Otherwise this post looks good.

Comment: Your code seems to read, `set counter = inputbox` then `Do until counter = inputbox` do you see the issue>?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I wasn't sure if I should do it or I was hoping user would, I'll check out your indenter when I'm not at work, I'm horrible with my indenting to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Dim counter As Integer
> counter = InputBox("Enter number of Cycles")
> ```

You're trusting the user to enter a valid number here. I'd pull that instruction into its own function, but the main problem is with the next line:

> ```
> Do Until counter = InputBox
> ```

`InputBox` is a function with a *required* `Prompt` parameter... what you probably mean to do is to have *another* variable (say, `cycleCounts`), and then `Do Until counter = cycleCounts`.

```
On Error Resume Next 'suppresses runtime errors
Dim cycleCounts As Integer
cycleCounts = InputBox("Enter number of cycles") 'possible type mismatch here
On Error GoTo 0 'restores runtime errors **IMPORTANT**
'note: cycleCounts is 0 if an error was raised

Dim counter As Integer
Do Until counter = cycleCounts
    counter = counter + 1
    '...
Loop
```

`On Error Resume Next` shouldn't be allowed to just merrily keep executing in an error state - that makes the code much harder to debug than necessary.

There are other issues, too: `Range.Find` will return `Nothing` if it doesn't find what it's looking for, which will cause the chained `.Select` member call to throw error 91 (which you are suppressing with `On Error Resume Next`). Remove the `.Select` and capture the result into an object variable instead:

```
    Dim result As Range
    Set result = Range("B2:B4000").Find(...)
    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        result.ClearContents
    End If
```

Note that there's no need to `Select` or `Activate` anything that way, and error-swallowing is healthily replaced with standard `If...End If` flow control.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu. That works a treat. Yes I understand that my code is inefficient. I'm as green as they come but one day I may be here assisting others like your good self. Thanks for the pointers Ill study them and look though my other code. Kind regards.